# Resetting axes after moving plots around?

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure, matlab-guide, matlab-gui

I am currently working on a GUI. I would like to have one 'axes' on which I can display multiple plots depending on which the user selects. Currently I have 2 bar plots and 2 surfc plots. I am setting the plots using

```
set(p1, 'Parent', axes1)
```

However it looks like when I set a bar plot to an axes that had a surfc there is still a z axis, and the same problem exists the other way around but wuth the lack of a z axis. This sample scripts demonstrates.

```
figure(1);
a1 = axes();
p1 = bar(1:5);

figure(2);
a2 = axes();
x = [1 2];
z = zeros(2);
p2 = surfc(x, x, z);

set(p1, 'Parent', a2)
set(p2, 'Parent', a1)
```

What is the best way to go about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're only working with a single axes, then you can change the [view](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/view.html) when you change from 3D (for the `surfc` plot) to 2D (the `bar` plot).

```
% Default 2D View
view(hax, 2);

% Default 3D View
view(hax, 3);
```

If you're allowing a user to toggle between the two, it may be worth not using the default 2D and 3D views, but rather in your button click callback, store the current view in a variable and then when they go back to the plot it keeps any custom viewpoint that the user applied. You can get the current viewpoint with the following:

```
[az, el] = view(hax);
```

**Mini-rant**

Also, in general it is best to assign the parent of your plot objects on construction. Most every graphics object constructor accepts the `Parent` parameter/value pair. It's a lot more robust that way because then the plot object is never drawn to the wrong axes.

```
fig1 = figure();
ax1 = axes('Parent', fig1);
p1 = bar(1:5, 'Parent', ax1);

fig2 = figure();
ax2 = axes('Parent', fig2);
p2 = surfc([1 2], [1 2], zeros(2), 'Parent', ax2);
```

When dealing with MATLAB graphics, I have *always* found it beneficial to be explicit about the parent when creating axes, plots, and other graphics objects. Never rely on `gca`, `gcf`, etc. as those all change if the user somehow clicks in the middle of your rendering.

Comment: Yes, but I have space for 'one' axes on my gui. Currently I place the axes with guide and then I switch the plot on the axes when the user clicks a button. I think I am limited to one axes here so this doesn't help much. Also it feel wrong saying one axes but you get the idea, I guess one set of axes

Comment: @Shatners Updated the answer.